# Converting a file server and Windows File Share to CIFS based share using Netapp Filer

Tags: windows, replication, network-attached-storage, server-message-block, cifs

My customer wants to decommission their old Windows Server 2008 file servers. The file shares contain lots of user home folders, group drive and data, application data etc. 
I would like to implement CIFS based solution using Netapp Filer and migrate all the data from the old servers to the Netapp NAS.
Then use some kind of logon script mount the shares when user client machines boot up. The access to the shares are controlled using AD Security groups at present. I would like to know will the existing folder permissions be messed up if the shares are migrated to a CIFS based share ? What would be the implication of migration and what is the best possible way to handle the data migration and permissions from the old windows based share to the new CIFS environment.

Comment: We don't want to use DFS as DFS has many issues. We thought of implementing Storage Replica which is part of Server 2016 Datacenter edition. But CIFS would be a better option as my customer already has a Netapps footprint. The problem is say we are using Robocopy and someone is making changes to a file or an application is making any change to a file, how will robocopy handle that? I heard robocopy is not so good in handling such cases and there might be a file version mismatch while the copying is getting done, isn't that the case?